# I wrote a partial soluton to Problem 2 of Project Euler, but I'm having a difficult time understanding how to sum the generated numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, fibonacci

For Problem 2 of Project Euler, you have to sum up all of the even numbers in the Fibonacci Series up to the number 4,000,000. I wrote the code to generate only the even numbers of the Fibonacci Series up to 4,000,000, but I can't seem to figure out how to sum them.

I have already tried things like appending the numbers to a list and then summing them, which throws an error. I have tried implementing code such as `sum =+ fibonacci(i)` which also throws the same error. Note: I am new to Python and I am still learning, so apologies if this comes off as noobish. I searched Stackoverflow and found somewhat similar questions, but the answers are code that is completely opposite to what I'm trying and/or some of the answers are flawed, which is why I posted my question.
After `if fibonacci(i) % 2 == 0:` I am lost as to what to do and I have been working at it for like an hour now.

```
def fibonacci(n):    
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
answer = 0
for i in range(0, 10):
    x = fibonacci(i)
    if x % 2 == 0:
    answer =+ x
print(answer)
```

I can't seem to understand how to sum those numbers up without getting the error: "int is not an iterable object."
The code should be printing out the sum of all of the even numbers of the Fibonacci Series up to 4,000,000, and then print out the result.
**NOTE**: I am aware using sum as a variable is shadowing...I only used it because another Stackoverflow solution recommended it (which was heavily upvoted), so please do not focus on this as the issue because *it is not the issue*. Even if I swap out `sum` for another random variable such as `x`, the same error gets thrown.

Comment: What code are you using that's throwing that exception?

Comment: If I do something like `sum = 0` and then within the loop I add `sum =+ fibonacci(i)` and then `print(sum)`, I get the error. I also get it with just trying `print(sum(F(i)))`. Note: I put `sum = 0` before `if fibonacci(i) % 2 == 0:` and everything else after `if fibonacci(i) % 2 == 0:`.

Comment: Try to use another variable name, `sum` is a built-in function and shadowing it is a bad idea, and please post the full code

Comment: I did post the full code in the OP. As I said, I have tried tons of different methods already, and I was only using `sum =` because someone recommended it in another solution on Stackoverflow. I'm aware that it is shadowing, but I figured why not try it anyway. The code still fails even if I swap `sum` out for a random variable such as `x`. I simply do not know where to go after `if fibonacci(i) % 2 == 0:`

Comment: That code that shows now cannot possibly be your code. Your last statement is an `if` statement with nothing under it. That code will result in `              ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`, not what you said. Please show the *actual* code and *actual* error. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Relax man, I just wanted to see what you tried to point out what is wrong with each approach

Comment: My (first) comment stands. You need to show us *runnable* code that produces the error message that you are discussing. Otherwise I do not know how to best answer your particular question since it relates to that error message. And as I explained in my second comment (now deleted), I will not just show you the full code since that would answer a Project Euler problem for you, going against the philosophy of that site.

Comment: I'm not asking for a solution. I'm trying to figure out why my code is not working. Look at stradivari's official solution below...that's what I first tried (before posting), among other variants, and VSCode throws the same error for all.

Comment: I added more code for clarity in-case anyone is confused as what I have tried. That's the complete code I have been working with.

Comment: Works fine after indenting and replacing `=+` with `+=` in the line `answer =+ x`

Comment: I'm testing that now, thanks. I think it's working since it's still running. I'll laugh at myself if this whole time, for whatever reason, I was typing out the operators in the wrong order, which seems like it may be the case. Not gonna lie, I'm used to programming in other languages where the order of such operators is unimportant, so this is interesting for me. Thanks for pointing that out. I'm probably going to mark your response below as the solution to my question since you have been the most helpful, and so far this seems to be the error in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "int is not an iterable object" is caused by passing a number to the `sum` function when it expects a iterable such as a list.

Following your code you can continue by adding all fibonacci numbers to a variable:

```
result = 0
for i in range(0, 10):
    f_i = fibonacci(i)
    if f_i % 2 == 0:
        result += f_i
print(result)
```

or by appending it to a list and using the `sum` function:

```
even_numbers = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    f_i = fibonacci(i)
    if f_i % 2 == 0:
        even_numbers.append(f_i)
print(sum(even_numbers))
```

Comment: I tried that already, it still throws the same error. That's why I'm so confused. I followed the Python 3 docs to a T, and the code still won't work. I'm using VSCode, but perhaps I should try a different editor/IDE? I'm unsure of the issue at this point, it's just odd. I might try my code in PyCharm next if everything keeps throwing errors. VSCode is up to date, all files are in appropriate places, the linter is good, no clue why the code won't work.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a issue with the IDE, to see what caused the error I need to see what you wrote in the whole file :/

Comment: I marked your comment as the solution to my question because you (1) worked out the issue using my exact code, and (2) caught the operator errors in my code, which I didn't even realize was a problem since I'm used to programming in other languages. Thanks again for your help, it is appreciated.

Comment: Happy to help man, I will shamelessly tell you to checkout a post that I wrote a while ago to help you continue with this particular problem: https://www.xiangchen.dev/faster-python/#lru_cache

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. Now that I know how to solve it with my solution, it's time for me to optimize since it's obviously slow lol, so your post will surely help out there.

Answer (score 0):

Why not sum the even numbers as you generate them rather than creating an intermediate list:

```
def sumEvenFibo(N):
    total = 0
    a,b = 2,3
    for _ in range(N//3):
        total += a # print(a) if you want to see which numbers are added
        a,b = a+2*b,2*a+3*b
    return total
```

*It takes roughly 5 minutes to get the sum of the even values up to the 4,000,000th fibonacci number (2.9 GHz Intel Core i9 laptop).  If only want the sum of even fibonacci numbers between 1 and 4,000,000, this should be fast enough (0.11 milliseconds)*

**EDIT** Optimized version:

This optimized version produces the sum of the first 4,000,000 even Fibonacci numbers in 8 seconds.

Or 2.6 seconds if you're only looking for the sum of even values out of the first 4M fibonacci numbers

Or 0.024 milliseconds if your's looking for the sum of even fibonacci numbers in the range 1 to 4,000,000. (which is only 34 Finobacci numbers, out of which only 11 are even)

```
# Function to return the Nth, Nth+1 Fibonacci number in log(N) time

def binFibo(N):
    a,b   = 1,1
    f0,f1 = 0,1
    r,s   = (1,1) if N&1 else (0,1)
    N   //=2
    while N > 0:
        a,b   = f0*a+f1*b, f0*b+f1*(a+b)
        f0,f1 = b-a,a
        if N&1: r,s = f0*r+f1*s, f0*s+f1*(r+s)
        N //= 2        
    return r,s

# Function to return the Nth, Nth+1 Even Fibonacci number in log(N) time
def binEvenFibo(N):
    a,b = binFibo(3*N)
    return a,a+2*b

# function to return the sum of the first N even Fibonacci numbers
# Log(N)^2 time
#
def binSumEvenFibo(N,rec=False):
    if N < 2: return [(0,2),(2,8)][N] if rec else [0,2][N]
    m     = N//2
    f0,f1 = binEvenFibo(m-1)
    p0,p1 = f0//2,f1//2
    a,b   = binSumEvenFibo(m,True)
    r     =  a + p0*a+p1*b
    s     =  b + p0*b+p1*(a+4*b)
    if N&1:
        d0,d1 = binEvenFibo(N)
        r,s = r+d0, s+d1
    return (r,s) if rec else r
```

Example use:

```
binSumEvenFibo(100) # sum of the first 100 even fibonacci numbers

# 290905784918002003245752779317049533129517076702883498623284700
```

Comment: I think it would be better if the code were optimized for speed, as 5 minutes is insane. I'm still going to stick with my current method, but thanks for responding with an alternative idea.

Comment: I added an optimized version (8 seconds for 4,000,000 even Fibonacci numbers)

Comment: I just realize that you probably weren't looking for 4,000,000 fibonacci numbers but  for even fibonacci numbers in the range 1 ... 4,000,000.  W'ere talking microseconds for that (not 5 minutes).   It got me to create a really fast algorithm for computing fibonacci numbers and their sum, so lots of fun anyway.